# all permutations of order 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory, permutation-cycles

I am trying to find all 3-Sylows of $A_{4}$. By definition, all of them have order 3. Now the question is how to find all permutations of order 3. Now, every permutation can be written as the product of disjoint cycles. Moreover, the order of the product is the lcm of the order of the cycles. Can I conclude from these two facts that the only elements in $S_{n}$ of order 3 are of the form (a b c)?

Comment: $A_4$ is not a large group. It may be instructive to list its elements and draw your conclusions from that.

Comment: Yes, every order three permutation in $S_4$ is a three-cycle.  Note that in $S_6$ and larger this increases to also include disjoint products of three-cycles, but of course those don't exist in $S_4$.  When moving to list or count them, it may help to do so in their canonical form with the smallest element involved in the cycle at the front of the cycle.

Comment: The answer by Dan gives you all permutations $(a,b,c)$ and the subgroups they generate. Some are equal, so in total you obtain $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups.